# Usuário ignorando orientações do uso correto do site e insiste em fazer o errado

Tags: debate, comportamento, resposta-aceita, usuarios

Não gosto de apontar e nem expor ninguém, mas neste caso eu já falei com o usuário ao menos 5 vezes e ele simplesmente me ignora e insiste no erro:

- [Perfil Edward Junior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/19903/edward-junior?tab=questions)

Ao invés dele marcar a resposta correta, ele simplesmente comenta ou cria uma *resposta* agradecendo.

Eu tentei falar com ele algumas vezes:

- [Como esconder iframe quando entrar no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45151/como-esconder-iframe-quando-entrar-no-site#comment103114_45157)
- [É possivel usar folha de estilo em um aplicativo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50671/%C3%89-possivel-usar-folha-de-estilo-em-um-aplicativo#comment148611_50671)
- [Erro na class, conexão com o FIREBIRD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72437/erro-na-class-conex%C3%A3o-com-o-firebird#comment148608_72437)

Houve um comentário mais antigo, porém eu apaguei.

Há algo que possamos fazer? Ou simplesmente "deixa lá"?

Comment: Me parece que apesar de não ser totalmente novato, o usuário não conhece as regras mínimas do SO. Na pergunta mais recente ele criou uma resposta como comentário, depois outra resposta com a solução. No entanto, outro usuário já tinha postado a solução que ele encontrou... Realmente seria interessante um mecanismo para (de forma bem educada), pedir pra ele se atentar às normas de conduta.

Comment: Eu costumo linkar para essa resposta: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117). Nem sempre funciona, mas não tem muito mais que se possa fazer a não ser continuar tentando dar orientações (eu acho).

Comment: @Molx acredito que o mecanismo é justamente o espaço para comentários. Se adicionar mais um meio de comunicação com o rapaz acho que ele vai ficar ainda mais perdido do que já está. Seriam muitas novidades de uma vez só para ele :)

Comment: @Math é mole? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72536/3635

Comment: Tá difícil, rs..

Comment: Só uma coisa, quando você for reclamar ou questionar o comportamento de um usuário específico no meta, coloque um comentário em pelo menos uma postagem dele chamando-o para se manifestar ou se defender (já fiz isso). Pois já aconteceu comigo mais de uma vez uma situação assim e não desejo a ninguém: É muito chato ter várias pessoas falando em público sobre você sem que você tenha sido chamado para se defender ou ao menos para ser ouvido.

Comment: Isso acontece muito em fóruns, acredito que se ele ver como funciona o modelo resolva isso.

Comment: @rray, verdade, ele responde como em foruns, e esta levando *down vote* sem questionar, não deve saber como funciona o mecanismo do SO.

Comment: @rray eu já o orientei 3 vezes e indiquei o tour. Me parece que ele prefere ignorar.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Eu acho que é ele que "não quer" saber como funciona. -- apenas opinião.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu pensei nisto, mas como ele estava me ignorando, pensei que isto não faria diferença. Mas realmente o mais correto é isto mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu acho que o fato dele dar respostas - mesmo capengas - mostra um interesse minimo que seja. Geralmente os que tem pouco interesse somem depois que uma resposta resolve o problema. Realmente não sei qual o caso do rapaz.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Desculpe discordar, mas acho que as respostas "capengas" foram mais por insistência de outros usuários. Não quero pegar ele pra Cristo, só que o fato dele voltar e ignorar os comentários dos colegas (e o meu) não me parece certo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o pior é que concordo com você, mas ele também poderia ignorar em responder. Por isso não entendo o caso dele... rs

Comment: @PapaCharlie para não julga-lo totalmente mau, posso dizer que ele leu os comentários e tentou fazer o que o comentário pede, mas não leu os links recomendados por "preguiça" e por este motivo ele está fazendo as coisas erradas.

Comment: No perfil de usuário dele consta "0 votos dados", e ele já tem reputação suficiente para isso há algum tempo.

Comment: Algo precisa ser feito pra chamar mais a atenção dos novos usuários a respeito do tour e das boas praticas. _Nem que metam um popup a cada página_. É preciso fazer uma pergunta como se fosse uma _redação do enem,_ de forma séria, não acho que só eu pense dessa forma.

Comment: Não é possivel criar algo onde questione o usuário se a pergunta foi satisfatória?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tenta orientar se tiveres paciência. Não se pode fazer muito mais...

Comment: Eu faria greve de respostas a esse cara, e só postaria, um link para este tópico dizendo: "Só receberá novas respostas MINHAS após se manifestar a respeito". Mas como não tenho muito conhecimento em PHP (que parece ser o forte dele), não poderia dar respostas a ele do mesmo jeito. hehe.

Comment: Deveria ter algo do tipo, se o cara tem X perguntas respondidas e não foi aceita nenhuma resposta, deveria bloquear para ele fazer perguntas e responder até que seja aceita algumas respostas em suas perguntas.

Comment: @MeuChapeu Ei, essa ideia é boa. Perguntas sem resposta marcada e sem atividade bloqueia a criação de novas perguntas.

Comment: @RSinohara tem algo semelhante, mas eu acho que ocorre quando o usuário não responde a nada. No caso ele respondeu as próprias perguntas (ae fica complicados)... Mudando de assunto, já deu pra perceber que ele não está nem ae mesmo com vários usuários lhe orientando ele finge que não vê, então só consigo pensar duas coisas, ou ele é muito burro (duvido muito) ou ele está fazendo de proposito ou é um fake estupido pra importunar. Já não sei de mais nada.

Comment: @Math lá se foi a minha ultima tentativa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76502/como-usar-ao-invés-de-abrir-tags-php#comment156377_76502

Comment: Sera que não rolaria uma ferramenta, ou uma rotina que geraria algum tipo de alerta toda vez que o utilizador entrasse, caso ele fosse reincidente e continuasse a manter uma media alta de votos negativos em perguntas e/ou respostas?

Comment: Existem alguns bloqueios automaticos, eu vou ver quais são, talvez exista alguma solicitação de nova funcionalidade no meta.SE @MarceloBonifazio. Ao menos por enquanto o Edward me respondeu e prometeu cumprir com as normas (ainda não fez nada :/ ). Vou esperar.

Comment: Acho que pode "deixar pra lá"... não é muito comum isso ocorrer dessa forma recorrente com um mesmo usuário. Então acho que se isso começar a ocorrer com muitos outros usuários de forma recorrente, aí sim podemos dar mais atenção e procurar medidas para esses casos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parece que é um daqueles casos que não adianta explicar, ele lê apenas por cima as coisas e acaba por não entender nada.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

- **Q:** Há algo que possamos fazer? Ou simplesmente "deixa lá"?
- **R:** Dependendo do caso acho que é bom abrir uma questão no meta, no entanto as vezes não é necessário. O necessário é *sempre comentar* o quanto for preciso e *a paciência* nos permitir. Não podemos obrigar ninguém a seguir o *fluxo ideal*, mas podemos sempre tentar incentivar.

<sup>**Relacionado:** [Devo questionar o usuário que recebeu resposta e não se manifestou?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4423/3635)</sup>

Comment: Paciência: http://i.stack.imgur.com/z5vmw.png o_Ø