# Devo questionar o usuário que recebeu resposta e não se manifestou?

Tags: debate

Utilizando o exemplo [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90070/ler-valor-input-type-file-d%C3%BAvida/90092#90092) questão, eu posso/devo questionar o usuário se as respostas que ele recebeu sanaram a dúvida postada?

Há usuários que parecem esquecer a pergunta, tendo **N** respostas e não se manifestam, mesmo sequer comentando.

Comment: O usuário ao qual se refere é razoavelmente participativo, aparentemente da feedback em quase todas respostas, o motivo deve ter sido porque ele simplesmente ainda não conseguiu testar ou implementar e provavelmente esta esperando alguma outra resposta. Eu mesmo tenho 2 perguntas com respostas, mas não marquei e ainda não dei feedback porque ainda não tive tempo de testar. Houve respostas minhas que levaram um ano pra ter feedback do autor. Recomendo que comente na pergunta pra tentar chamar atenção perguntando ao autor se a sua resposta lhe ajudou ou se não ficou claro. De resto é paciência.

Comment: Sim, Guilherme, esse caso foi apenas um exemplo de outros que já vi, não sendo necessariamente com resposta minha.

Comment: Bom dia Marcelo, então foi exatamente o que eu quis dizer com "Eu mesmo tenho 2 perguntas" e "Houve respostas minhas que levaram um ano pra ter feedback", quero dizer que isto é normal da comunidade e das pessoas, de resto é ter paciência.

Comment: Tranquilo. Só queria saber se alfinetar um usuário não seria mal interpretado pela comunidade. É claro que como o bigown disse, com educação e sendo sensato com a questão do tempo passado, até fazer o lembrete.

Comment: Sim, concordo totalmente :)

Comment: Chega o dia em que a gente até desiste disso, Marcelo. Se a pessoa dá feedback, fantástico, se não dá, azar, daqui a xx meses alguém dá um +1 e você fica "ó, ajudei alguém mais!" :) Ali no seu perfil do site principal aparece "aprox. 4 mil pessoas ajudadas", em teoria você ajudou 71 pessoas por cada pergunta/resposta, oxalá cada uma desse um voto!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dando o devido tempo, não sendo incisivo, sendo imparcial em relação às outras respostas, e principalmente feito com educação, enfim, se for no melhor interesse da comunidade, não há mal algum em fazer isto. Pelo contrário.

Parece que fez certinho no exemplo.

Alguns usuários somem mesmo. Outros podem escolher não se manifestar. Ainda que seja ruim para a comunidade, é um direito dele. Mas um lembrete pode resolver o caso da pessoa ter apenas esquecido.